# CSS bug causes elements to re-render when scrolling

Tags: css

I'm trying to figure out why my third element div.servicespost re-renders when you scroll past it.

See [here](http://www.thelucyfoundation.com). The third post under "What's on" re-renders on a new row as you scroll through it. I can't give any other information about it. Has someone seen this before?

The inspector shows nothing out of the ordinary, or any errors at all.

Comment: your site says "coming soon". Please post code.

Comment: The link says "Coming Soon".

Comment: Your parallax script seems to be removing `onScreen` classes from 2 of the columns, causing a layout change.

Comment: Right. Why would it do that? I'm trying to think of a more intelligent question. Ha ha. Perhaps I should say... how do I stop it?

Comment: This behavior is due to onScreen class. In the inspector when you scroll past the services div you will notice the onScreen class being applied to various elements.

Comment: @square_eyes see my answer for a somewhat long-winded explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few factors that are causing issues:

1) There are margins at play that are being stripped when you add the `.onScreen` class. This wouldn't necessarily be a problem if the classes were all added and removed at the same time, but that leads to the second problem.

2) The columns are not equal heights, which means the `.onScreen` class is being removed at different times.

The end result is the third column (`.postwrapper-3`) having it's `.onScreen` class still active while the other two don't. Since it uses a negative margin to stay aligned properly and the `.onScreen` class strips that negative margin, it gets shifted to a new line.

Simple fix, remove the margin clearing from the `.onScreen` class:

```
#services .onScreen {
  margin: 0; //remove this
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't want to change the theme files if possible. Why are the columns different sizes? Is it because the content is different sizes? Or perhaps I put some CSS in my child theme that broke the rendering up/down the chain? More vague questions I know!

Comment: The content is dictating the height difference, yes. Both the column base styling (with the problematic margins) and the onScreen styling that breaks the layout appear to be in the parent theme stylesheet. There is no simple way to fix this without editing that file, unfortunately.

Comment: OK I'll do that and contact the theme developer. Thanks again:)

Comment: Is it possible to remove this in the child stylesheet? `#services .onScreen {
  margin: none;
}` doesn't seem to work.